# How do I upload a CSV file into Mysql on MacOS?

Tags: mysql, macos, load-data-infile

I am using the following lines of code:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'CA_DRU_proj_2010-2060.csv'
INTO TABLE pop_proj
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' , '
ENCLOSED BY ' " '
LINES TERMINATED BY ' \n '
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

The error I am receiving is:

Error Code: 1148. The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

My version of mysql is version 8.0.16

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you check that the MySQL version is 8.0.16? I know I have had issues in the past where the version being run on my server is different than the one on my local and had a miscommunication between environments when running a query..

Comment: @AaronMorefield I just clicked the "MySQL Workbench" in the upper toolbar. Then I clicked on "About MySQL Workbench" and it displayed my version in a pop-up.

Comment: That tells you the version of MySQL Workbench, not the version of the server. Try running the SQL query: `SELECT @@version;` - that will tell you the version of the server.

Comment: (1) What is the reason to use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE when the file is local already? (2) You do not specify the directory where the file is posessed in - how MySQL must determine its location? (*) Remove LOCAL, put the file into @@secure_file_priv directory, and specify complete pathname in the statement.

Answer (score 3):

You need both the server and the client to enable local-infile import.

The server needs to enable `local_infile=1`. You can put this in your `my.cnf` options file, or you can enable it dynamically on a running server with `SET GLOBAL local_infile=1;`

You also need to tell the client to allow it. Do this by starting the client:

```
mysql --local-infile=1 ...
```

Since MySQL 8.0.19, the error message is more clear:

> ERROR 3950 (42000): Loading local data is disabled; this must be
> enabled on both the client and server side

See also:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local-security.html
- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94396

---

Update: If you use MySQL Workbench instead of the `mysql` command line client, you can enable local-infile in the options on the Advanced tab of your connection profile. See highlighted line below:

[image]

Comment: I ran the line you had suggested above  SET GLOBAL local_infile=1;         And I while it run smoothly- when I went back to run my initial line of code; I received the same error as earlier.

Comment: Did you understand the part where I mentioned that *both* client and server must have options set to enable local infile? These options are set separately. Unless you do both, it's not enough.

Comment: Ah I see. I was able to enable it dynamically for the server, but I am still unsure on how to enable for the client. Thank you for all of your continued help.

Comment: I don't know which client you're using.

Comment: How can I check to see which client I am using? I apologize for the confusion, this is my first time learning SQL.

Comment: You said in an earlier comment that you're using MySQL Workbench. Good luck.

Comment: The statement I typed is in a query tab I typed into mySQL. I downloaded mySQL off of the mySQL website, and then created a database within mySQL. Now I am trying to import a csv with the data for this database into mySQL.

Comment: This worked great for me!  I was able to import a CSV of 200,000 records in 10 seconds! Previously tried the GUI import and that looked like it was going to take hours. Using MYSQL Workbench in Ubuntu.

Comment: @MarsAndBack, I'm glad it helped you! Yes, I hardly ever use MySQL Workbench. I've heard from multiple people that its data import feature is very slow. I guess it's used only for small sets of data for testing.