# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I am getting this error "**LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access**" while working on MySQL workbench. I am new to Mysql. I found a similar post in StackOverflow but none of them work for me.

```
CREATE DATABASE assignment02;
USE assignment02;

CREATE TABLE `hss_electives`(
                         sno INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                         roll_number INT,
                         sname CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                         cid CHAR(50),
                         cname CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                         PRIMARY KEY(roll_number, cid)
                         );


 LOAD DATA LOCAL infile 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/hss_electives.csv'
 INTO TABLE hss_electives
 fields terminated BY ','
 lines terminated BY '\n'
 ignore 1 rows;
```

My local_infile option is set to "**ON**"
[image: My local_infile option is set to "ON"]

My secure_file_priv is set to the same directory where my CSV file is.
[image: Secure_file_priv =]

My csv file look like this :
[image]

Comment: There's an option you need to set in the client as well as the server. I show how to do this in MySQL Workbench in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65484140/20860

Comment: Remove LOCAL option (file is local already). Check does the account has FILE privilege.

Comment: Thanks, @Akina removing word "local" works!

Comment: After applying @BillKarwin 's linked solution, and KEEPING the word "LOCAL", everything worked for me. Removing "LOCAL" did not work for me initially.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got this answer, There is two way to correct this error :

1. As pointed by [Akina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10138734/akina), Removing "local" word from load data local infile worked!.
2. **Solution without removing local keyword** :

   - Go to your connection and then choose EDIT CONNECTION.
     [image]
   - Then Choose Advanced option and Add this line : OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1;
     [image]
     -Thanks to [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin) for suggesting this method!